# save and populate node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I have Course Schema like below

```
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    current_education: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    course_name: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Course'
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mobile_number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

and I'm trying to make relationship student to the course. In the controller, I'm trying to populate the course details based on the course ID like below

```
exports.createStudent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const student = new Student(req.body);
        const result = await student.save().then(t => Course.findById(req.body.course_name).populate('courses'));
        if (!result) res.send('something went wrong');
        res.send(result)
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e);
    }
}
```

In the postman how I'm posting you can check it below

```
{
    "name":"Ram",
    "current_education":"B.tech",
    "course_name":"5cb804f1e97ba91cb8ca9dac",
    "address":"Bangalore",
    "mobile_number":7894561236
}
```

**Important:** Here courseID is existed in the database
the data is saved successfully in the database but the course details not populated except id. the resultant data in the database look like below
[image]

Comment: You want student data with course details, Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly @Jack

Comment: Refresh the page and checkout the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want Student details along with the course details:

Here's how you achieve it:

```
exports.createStudent = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const student = new Student(req.body);
        const result = await student.save().then(t =>
            Student.findById(student._id).populate('course_name')); // Pass new ID and then populate the "course_name"
        if (!result) res.send('something went wrong');
        res.send(result)
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your query!

Comment: Why do you want course name in creation? In Schema you have added ref for "course" collection, this means you have to store just ID of "course", which you are already doing! Why do you want to populate?

Comment: In the postman it giving a whole object  including course details and student details but in the database, it is saving only ID(which we passing). How to save a whole object including student details and course details